# Group documents by subdocument field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use mongo's aggregation framework to group a collection based on a timestamp and use the $out to output it to a new collection. Apologies, I am new to Mongo

I have the following JSON structure in my collection

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "parent" : [
        {
            "child" : {
                "child_id" : "1",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2010-01-08T17:49:39.814Z")
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have been trying

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
        { $project: { child_id: '$parent.child.child_id', timestamp: '$parent.child.timestamp' }},
        { $group: { cid: '$child_id', ts: { $max: '$timestmap'} }},
        { $out : 'mycollectiongrouped'}
        ]))
```

however getting this error. Any ideas, I assume I am probably using the project incorrectly.

> [thread1] Error: command failed: {
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "the group aggregate field 'cid' must be defined as an expression inside an object",
>       "code" : 15951
>   } : aggregate failed :
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13

Comment: You are missing the `_id` field. Also you should consider to use a valid date object.

Comment: thanks. regarding the valida date object I am using ISODate(). Will edit the question appropriately

Comment: Is the "parent" field always one element array? what is your `mongod` version?

Comment: yes it is, with multiple children. I am looking to group children based on max timestamp so I get one child with the max timestamp for each parent. Version is 3.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: { 
        _id: "$parent.child.child_id",
        timestamp: {$max: "$parent.child.timestamp"}
    }},
    {$project: {
        cid: {$arrayElemAt: ["$_id", 0]},
        ts: {$arrayElemAt: ["$timestamp", 0]},
        _id: 0
    }},
    {$out: "groupedCollection" }
])
```

You are missing the `_id` which is mandatory for the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage. That being said since the "parent" field in your document is one element array, the `$group` stage should be the first stage in the pipeline.

By making the `$group` stage the first stage, you will only need to project one document per group instead of all documents in the collection.

Note that the resulted document fields are array hence the use of the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt) operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stage.

Comment: Thank you for the response and explanation. That makes sense now I see it. Tried it there on my Mongo Collection and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `_id` field for the `$group`. This `_id` is what determines which documents are grouped together. For instance, if you want to group by `child_id`, then do `_id: "$child_id"`. In that case, you can omit the `cid` field (in this case, you can just change `cid` to `_id`).